# Validating the user input in javascript, after correcting a typo and resubmitting wouldn't break out of the else construct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, loops

I have a coupon code field which has to accept a set of coupon keys. I wrote the below code for the validation. If the user enters an invalid key at first, it alerts "Invalid Key" then if he corrects that invalid key and submits, It does nothing. I see that it's not coming out of the else construct. Please suggest

```
<form name="offerpage" autocomplete="off" action="/blah/blah blah_servlet/" method="post" onsubmit="return validateCoupon());">

<input type="text" maxlength="07" class="form-cntrl" name="COUPON" id="COUPON" value="${vs['COUPON']}" required="" style ="width: 100px">

function validateCoupon()
                    {

                        var couponkey = ["ABCDEF1", "ABCDEF2", "ABCDEF3","ABCDEF4", "ABCDEF5", "ABCDEF6", "ABCDEF7"];

                        var keyinput = $('#COUPON').val().trim().toUpperCase();

 }
                        if(couponkey.indexOf(keyinput)>-1)
                            {   
                            alert("Awesome");  //testing the flow
                            return true;        
                            }

                        else
                            {
                                alert("Invalid Key");
                                return false;

                            }



     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a closing bracket `}` after this line `var keyinput = ...`. Thus it closes the scope of function `validateCoupon`. As a result, statements after that bracket are not executed as part of the function. Just remove that bracket and your code should run fine.

```
function validateCoupon() {

  var couponkey = ["ABCDEF1", "ABCDEF2", "ABCDEF3", "ABCDEF4", "ABCDEF5", "ABCDEF6", "ABCDEF7"];

  var keyinput = $('#COUPON').val().trim().toUpperCase();

  // } --> This bracket is not required.
  if (couponkey.indexOf(keyinput) > -1) {
    alert("Awesome"); //testing the flow
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Invalid Key");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This onsubmit="return validateCoupon());"> also had a extra closing round bracket on the end which causes it to error as well.

Comment: @Nisarg shah and dougtesting.net   Additional brackets are my typo here, I'm using eclipse, so these could be identified on run. I checked my code in eclipse, brackets were fine but still, the issue persists. Any clue???

Comment: Are you using any third party library? I don't know this syntax in value field: `${vs['COUPON']}`

Comment: @nisarg shah... Its JSTL